# Semiconductors forward bias

Tags: diodes

Well why the depletion region of the pn junction is decreased in forward bias condition and not minimized? Current will start flowing neutralizing all donor ions and so there will be no depletion region left.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the difference between decreased on minimized?

Comment: It is minimized. If you take a look at the I/U sheet of a PN diode, you see the equivalent resistance gets lower the higher the current.

Comment: Decreased:the potential of the depletion region is reduced in half for example,Minimized:the potential of the depletion region is 0

Comment: You will always have ohmic resistance, and thus, a voltage drop. It's not possible to get this to zero. It's still a semiconductor, not a superconductor.

Comment: A lot of this was covered recently here: [Diode Depletion Region Forces](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/426270/11683).